# fill a webrowser html textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

i'm trying to fill a textbox in a webbrowser with my winform application if you guys have any idea of how should i do it.

here's the code :

```
<input autocomplete="number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number" data-current-field="number" class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-34 unknown" placeholder="number" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;">
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetAttribute method after getting the HTML element (by Id, class or name). For instance:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("number").SetAttribute("value", "5");
```

There isn't much information from your question, so I think my solution will work fine. Hope it helps!